# Tanzania first day of the week

Tags: calendar

To correctly setup the calendar on my project, I need to know which day is the first of the week in Tanzania.

Seems like Google doesn't know, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am referring to the main source of internationalization data in IT-world (used for Java, C# etc.):

There is no explicit entry for TZ (= ISO-3166-2 code of Tanzania) in the weekData-section of [CLDR-data](http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/tags/release-31-0-1/common/supplemental/supplementalData.xml). In such a case CLDR-data of unicode corporation says that the code "001" should be selected. And the data for "001" are:

Monday as first day of week and 1 as minimal count of first week in year.